# extracting hash tag value from a string

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to extract a hash tag value from a string using jquery and regular expressions.

```
blah blah #INeedThis blah blah
```

I've tried this :-

```
/^#?(.*)$/
```

Which nearly works. It extracts every thing after the hash tag so I get this :-

```
#INeedThis blah blah
```

How can I make the regualr expression get just the hash value without the hashtag so that I end up with this:-

```
INeedThis
```

There may also be more than one hash tag value in the string

Comment: Are you always guaranteed to have spaces between your content?

Comment: Yes, there will always be spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a **non-capturing** group for the `#` and a **capturing** group for the string portion:

```
/(?:#)([A-Za-z]+)/g
```

In the array that is returned, the item at index 1 will be "INeedThis"

**Usage Example:**

```
var myRe = /(?:#)([A-Za-z]+)/g;
var myArray = myRe.exec("blah blah #INeedThis blah blah");

var content = document.getElementById("content");
content.innerHTML = myArray[1];
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/zrqjbbjt/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try the regex bellow

`(^|\s)([#][a-zA-Z\d-]+)`

Working regex example:

https://regex101.com/r/kJ2qR3/2

Comment: Why is the `@` in your regular expression? And what if the value behind the hash is anything other than a-z, a digit or a dash?

Comment: what is your jsfiddle?

Comment: @putvande I think (^|\s)([#][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) will be more clear for you

Answer (score 1):

`/#(\S+)/g` would match everything behind a hashtag that isn't a space.

```
'blah blah #INeedThis blah blah'.match(/#(\S+)/g);
```

would result in `["#INeedThis", "INeedThis"]`